# Using awk to change an entire column of both positive and negative values, to just negative?

Tags: awk

I use awk alot to manipulate xyz text files (lat,long,elevation). I have a specific file that has both positive and negative values in the z column, I would like all of these to be negative. So {$3*-1} wont work because it reverses the negatives to positives, I want all negatives. Seems like something that is possible but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to negate all positive values, and leave negative values alone, the conditional operator will work:

```
$3 > 0 ? -1 * $3 : $3
```

Comment: ironically this is probably better than the answers to the question that this question is marked a duplicate of